# HTML form POST shows server's reply

Tags: html, forms, http-post

I have a simple HTML form.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <body>
      <center>
         <form action="MYLINK" method="POST">
            Tell your device what to do!<br>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="args" value="on">Turn the Light on.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="args" value="off">Turn the Light off.
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Do it!">
         </form>
      </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

When the submit is clicked, the page redirects and Server's JSON reply is shown. I dont want that.

Comment: Post function handling the submit.

Comment: Theres no function on my end. Its a cloud service developed by someone else. I'm just trying to use it.

Comment: Then there really isn't much for anyone to go by in order to help you.

Comment: I suggest you to try a workaround. Post this form to a server side script in your web application and process cloud service response in it.

Comment: Cant i use some script to fire the POST on button click instead of the HTML form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an `IFRAME` in the page and then added it as the form's target

```
<form action="MYLINK" method="POST" target="hidden-form">
...
</form>
<IFRAME style="display:none" name="hidden-form"></IFRAME>
```

Now the reply from server is not visible.